# What are the options for a prepaid SIM card in Montevideo, Uruguay?

Tags: cellphones, pre-pay, uruguay, montevideo

What are the options for pre-paid SIM cards in Uruguay (Montevideo)? What are the options for pre-paid data plans/packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data via cellphone is one of [the most competitive marketplaces in Uruguay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecommunications_in_Uruguay#Mobile_Wireless_in_Uruguay).

> Vendors are shifting from 3G to 4G, starting in the area around
>   Montevideo. From a consumer's standpoint the only discouraging trend
>   in this market is the adoption of data volume caps by all vendors. As
>   of August 2012 no vendor web-site offered an unlimited mobile internet
>   data plan (the closest was an "unlimited during nights and weekends"
>   from Claro.)

In terms of prepaid data plans, there are several available, from Claro, Antel or Movistar.  I won't copy and paste verbatim as I'm sure they're likely to change with time, but an up-to-date wiki is maintained at
[Uruguay Prepaid Plans](http://wiki.apnchanger.org/Uruguay#Prepaid_plans) on APNCharger.org.

Comment: Will these prepaid SIM cards work for a Mifi as well?

Comment: @DanishKhan, in theory, I guess, as they just take regular sims, right?

Comment: Yea, I figured as long as the SIM has a data plan it should work. I was just curious if anyone knew.